# Cumulative distribution function, integration problem

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Given the continuous Probability density function $f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x-4, & 2\le x\le3  \\ 0 ,& \text{else}\end{cases}$

Find the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$.

The formula is $F(x)=\int _{ -\infty  }^{ x }{ f(x) } $

---

#### My Solution

The first case is when $2\le x\le3$  then $$\int_2^x {(2u-4)} \, du=[u^2-4u]_2^x=x^2-4x-4+8=x^2-4x+4$$

so $F(x)=x^2-4x+4 , \text{ for } 2\le x\le 3$

#### The Problem

Now I have the cases where $x<2 \text{ and } x>3$ , ($\int_{-\infty}^{x}0 \, dx$) but I am not sure how to do it. I would appreciate if someone could show me the solution of this two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general technique to deal with such type of questions is to split up the integral at the points where the density $f$ has different specifications, i.e. at $y=2$ and $y=3$. If $y<2$, then
$$
F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^yf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^y0\,\mathrm dx=0,
$$
and if $2\leq y\leq 3$, then
$$
\begin{align}
F(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^yf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^20\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^y(2x-4)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=0+\left[x^2-4x\right]_2^y=y^2-4y+4.
\end{align}
$$
Lastly, if $y>3$ then
$$
\begin{align}
F(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^2 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^3 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_3^y f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^2 0\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^3 (2x-4)\,\mathrm dx+\int_3^y 0\,\mathrm dx\\
&=0+1+0=1.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

In the ranges $x < 2$ and $x>3$ the PDF is zero and contibutes nothing to the integral, and therefore the CDF is constant in these ranges. **You** have already done most of the work and the CDF is 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 
  0, & x < 2 \\
  x^2-4x+4,  & 2 \le x\le3  \\ 
  1 ,& x > 3
\end{cases}$$

Comment: could you please explain the case $x>3$ why is it 1 ?

Comment: As I already said, the PDF is zero for $x>3$ and therefor the value is $F(x) = F(3) = 1, \quad x > 3, \quad$ because $\int_{3}^{x}0dt = 0.$

Answer (score 2):

when x<2, it is $\int_{-\infty}^{x}0du=0$

when x>3, it is obviously 1. You should research the properties of $F(x)$

Comment: could you please explain a bit more the case $x>3$ why is it 1 ?

Comment: $F(x)$ is increasing and $lim F(x)=1$ for $x-->infinity$

Comment: Oh, thanks now I get it. This is actually one of the three characteristic of continuous CDF.

Comment: @Devid: Another way to see why $F(x)=1$ for $x>3$ is to split up the integral as follows: If $x>3$, then $$
\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^2 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^3 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_3^x f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^2 0\,\mathrm dx+\int_2^3 (2x-4)\,\mathrm dx+\int_3^x 0\,\mathrm dx=0+1+0=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @StefanHansen thanks very much this was very helpful. I think actually this is the best solution. If you posted it as answer i would accept.